# WSDL validation with soap 1.2

Tags: soap, wsdl, standards-compliance

Is there are any wsdl-validation profiles available to check the ws-i compliance of wsdl file with soap 1.2?

Or I need to switch to soap 1.1 to pass the WS-I compliance test?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use the [following tools](http://www.ws-i.org/deliverables/workinggroup.aspx?wg=testingtools) to test your service. I guess they should also work for SOAP 1.2 (haven't tried it though).

You could try to use the tools by themselves but I think it would be easier to [do it with SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/Working-with-soapUI/preferences.html#WS-I%20Settings%20Tab). If I'm not mistaken, the BSP Test Tools is what's used by default by SoapUI to test WS-Interoperability.

Good luck!